# How to store and use length of elements in scss?

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to store the width of a checkbox and container in scss in angular as for example `$checkbox-width` and `$cont-width`? Because I have a checkbox and a dropdown next to it. I need the checkbox to be center aligned so I used `.justify-content-center` and the dropdown
`position: absolute;
'right: 1rem;' as it needs to be right beside it

In medium screens this works

[image: Checkbox in md screen]

But in lg screens the space is not right. It would be nice if I could add `right: $cont-width/2 - $checkbox/2;` instead of using `@media` for each screen size and sorry if this is a weird question but just wondering if this is possible if I did not manually set the width of the container and checkbox but can I get it and store it in variables in css? Thanks

[image: Checkbox in lg screen]

Comment: DId you use display: flex and justify-content: center together ?

Comment: Did you try use calc() function?

Comment: @WalterWhite yes

Comment: @WalterWhite thanks `calc()` is what I was looking for. Is it possible to get the width of a container and checkbox that I have manually not set the width?

Comment: you must use java script in css() I think we don't have that function to get parent container width; Inspect parent width and set that static value in calc function() but if you want site would be responsive, must use another solution width must be define as % units

Comment: @WalterWhite that sounds much longer than three lines of `@media` so I will stick with that, thanks!